# Process one giant access.log file

Tags: logstash

I have a large access.log file with about 6 months of data and 200K lines; I have used grokdebug to make sure that the lines are filtered properly, etc; I am storing the output of logstash in Elastic Search v1.1.1.

The issue I am noticing is that there is only one index being created (the day that I run the logstash agent) and the rest of the entries are ignored; I had read on the logstash site that by default there is  one index per day; but how can I tell logstash to process the entire file (and create the respective indexes for each day)?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated; I have read the documentation but could not find much info on this or perhaps I am not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the timestamp field is set to the time that the log is received.

To overwrite that with a timestamp from the log record, you use the ['date' filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date).